# Bar Chart Category Text Direction

Tags: excel, vba

I have data as follows in a table bellow:

[image]

I would like to create a bar chart with column1 and colum2 as category's. When I do this column1's text direction on the chart becomes vertical. See image bellow. I can change column2's text direction from vertical to horizontal, but the first column stays vertical. How do I change column1's text direction to horizontal? Is there an option that I am over looking or a VBA approach that can fix this?

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible since this feature is not thought for such approach. Let the first "col1" in your data, delete the next three. Then rename the next "col1" to "col2" and delete the following. Now you should see how it is thought. You could concatenate column1 and column2 in a helper column and use this helper column as axis label range.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Making a helper column and concatenating work just great. Why didn't I think of that...